# How can I use c# ViewBag variable in Jquery Selector?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I want to make a Jquery Selector based on the value of an input field. And this should be dynamically with a C# Variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var company = @ViewBag.company;
        $("input[value='"+ company +"']").attr("checked", "checked");
    });
</script>
```

Somehow its always give me an error. Further Info: The ViewBag Variable is sometimes something like: "Bank of Scotland". so it has withspace in it. Is this the problem?
**EDIT:** The Error is something like "missing ';' in statement" on the first line of the ready function.

I have in my HTML then a radio button with the value "Bank of Scotland" and And the ViewBag Variable is "Bank of Scotland" as well. When I just hardcode this it works:

```
 $("input[value='Bank of Scotland']")[...more code...]
```

Does anyone know, how to fix this? 
Thx for your help :)

Comment: If you get an error, make sure you include it in the question.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's something like "missing ; in statement" on the first line of the ready function. I totally forgot to include that. I made an edit, thx guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line

```
var company = '@ViewBag.company';
```

And it should be like this

```
$(function () {
        var company = '@ViewBag.company';
        $("input[value='"+ company +"']").attr("checked", "checked");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
var company = '@(ViewBag.company)';
```

In your example output will be (with your code):

```
var company = Bank of Scotland;
```

which is not valid js...

Answer (score 1):

For me, I never directly assign C# code to JavaScript variable, because I want to separate C# and JavaScript.

I set the Viewbag value to hidden field. Then I retrieve from jQuery like this.

```
$('.hidden-field').val()
```

Or you can directly assign like this:

```
var data = "@ViewBab.value";
```

Comment: Good point with the hidden field. But I was lookin for a pragmatic solution. So I think I'll go with the second option, because separating JS an Razor is not my first prio right know. But thx to for this hint. :)